# Deploying and using Shiny with R on a huge dataset

Tags: r, shiny

I have 3 gig dataset, millions of rows and around 20 columns. I want to allow user to query the dataset online. I started playing around with Shiny and R and very quickly using a small sample of the dataset I had a app.

My question is whats the best deployment method for here for the entire dataset on the web using R and Shiny? Second question are there better solutions here which still keep R in the picture as a way for me to create the functionality?

Thanks
JK

Comment: Quite a general Q. it depends how expensive each operation is on your own machine, does it take secs or millisecs? thats a function of the query as well as data. If cheap just deploy, if a bit expensive try data.table, if really quite expensive maybe optimise with Rcpp and if still unfeasible try RSQLite.

Answer (score 0):

I have used SQLite via the RSQLite extension pretty successfully. Three gig should not be an issue for RSQLite I have obtained fairly decent performance form Sqlite.

Comment: Hi Xiaodai - thanks for the response, what would I need to do to my shiny app to deploy it with SQLite - would it mean a rewrite?